# Armel cross-compilation on Debian (toolchain repository problem)

Tags: c++, cross-platform

I am compiling some code from armel architecture using Debian toolchain. I have found this page https://wiki.debian.org/CrossToolchains however, when I am failing to get an archive toolchain key using command from the instructions:
`curl http://emdebian.org/tools/debian/emdebian-toolchain-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -`

Seems that repository http://emdebian.org/tools/debian is not available anymore. Does anybody knows is there any issues with is now?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As it explains on the [debian page](https://wiki.debian.org/EmdebianToolchain), the Emdebian is not supported anymore and it is suggested to use CrossToolchains package instead.

Based on [this page](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmPorts), you may use arm-linux-gnueabihf as it supports ARM v6 and v7 as you need.